# why do I need the @ for setting variable value

Tags: ruby

I'm a little confused about scope of variables, in ruby I wrote a test program:

```
class Test 
        attr_reader :tester 
        def initialize(data) 
                @tester = data 
        end 

        def getData 
                 tester 
        end
end 

puts Test.new(11).getData
```

now this works fine, the attr_reader, but my confusion is that since I've define attr_reader :tester then why can't I go tester = data rather then @tester = data, because when retrieving the data in getData I only have to write tester and not @tester

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `attr_reader` is equivalent to

```
class Test
  def initialize(data) 
    @tester = data 
  end 

  # attr_reader defines this method for you
  def tester
    @tester
  end

  def getData 
    tester 
  end
end
```

In your `getData` method using `tester` is equivalent to `self.tester`. If you use `@tester` you access the variable directly. When you use `tester` you access the variable via the getter method.

Comment: but If I replaced attr_reader with attr_accessor :tester does that not mean that I should be able to do just test = data? (this does not work)

Comment: Yes, if you use `attr_accessor :tester` you will also get a setter method. Could you post the example where you use `attr_accessor` and `tester = data` does not work?

Answer (score 0):

attr_reader means that should read: "The corresponding instance variable getter and setter 
methods will be created for you." so that first we get data and then we set that data.

Answer (score 0):

`some_name =` syntax without the explicit receiver is interpreted as a local variable assignment. In order to do an assignment to an instance variable, you have to explicitly set the receiver even if it is `self`. In this case, `self.tester =`.